# Search an array return partial matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, mootools

I need to search an associative array's values for a string, but only the beginning of the string example:

```
var stack = ['aba', 'abcd', 'ab', 'da', 'da'];
```

a search on stack for the value `a` would return `['abc, 'abcd', 'ab']`, and for `b` would just return b while a search for 'd' would return `[da', 'da']` ...any way to do that?

Im trying to do like an autocomplete select box, but its custom so i need to moditor text events and search my array of items to get the index of the first match while the user is typing.

Comment: actually all i need returned is the index of the closest match

Comment: mootools is fine as well

Comment: That's no associative array. You can't access "aba" through `stack['aba']`. You also have an unencapsulated string after "ab".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upvoted @Mrbuubuu but you can do this as a prototype and pass the filter element through the String `.contains` to be more mootools-ish and cater for matches in the middle, like 'cd' which should return results.

eg case, an array of brands, one of which is `the north face` and a user searching for `north` should return the matched brand but it won't as they missed `the`

additionally, you need to make sure the case is lowered on the search string and the stack array elements when you compare values.

here's an example with an input that works: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/M2Tep/

```
(function() {
    Array.implement({
        subStr: function(what) {
            return this.filter(function(el) {
                return el.charAt(0) == what;
                // return el.contains(what); // any position match
            });
        }
    });
})();

// return the original array elements
console.log(['aba', 'abcd', 'ab', 'da', 'da'].subStr("d")); 
// ["da", "da"]
```

alternatively, you mentioned in a comment that all you really wanted to get were just the indexes in your original array:

```
(function() {
    Array.implement({
        getIndexes: function(what) {
            var indexes = [];
            this.each(function(el, index) {
                if (el.charAt(0) == what)
                    indexes.push(index);
            });
            return indexes;
        }
    });
})();


console.log(['aba', 'abcd', 'ab', 'da', 'da'].getIndexes("d")); 
// [3,4]
```

although since this does not return the array, it would break chaining hence it should not be a prototype of array but just a function.

Comment: What is `Array.implement`? I've never seen that before and can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: it's a mootools specific method to extend the Array.prototype - it's like saying `Array.prototype.getIndexes = () => ...`

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks for the followup.

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Extend the Array object
 * @param candid The string to search for
 * @returns Returns the index of the first match or -1 if not found
*/
Array.prototype.searchFor = function(candid) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].indexOf(candid) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Then you can use it like :

```
var index = stack.searchFor('a');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use mootools to do this, you can use the filter method from mootools:

```
function search(arr, letter) { 
    var matches = arr.filter(function(str) {
        return str.charAt(0) == letter;
    });

    return (matches.length > 0) ? matches : letter;
}

search(stack, 'd'); //returns ['da', 'da']
```

Comment: in new browsers filter is built-in method of array.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest vanilla javascript to achieve this is

```
var stack = ['aba', 'abcd', 'ab', 'da', 'da', undefined, , false, null, 0];
var prefixTextToFind = "a"; //b, c or d

var matches = stack.filter(function(stackValue){
  //get rid of all falsely objects
  if(stackValue) {
    return (stackValue.substring(0, prefixTextToFind.length) === prefixTextToFind);
  }
}); //["aba", "abcd", "ab"]
```

Comment: What if the array contains: `here-i-come` and i want to see if the Url: `http://mypage.com/noway/here-i-come` has the value from the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.startWith = function(c){
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0, len=this.length; i<len; i++){
        if(this[i].indexOf(c) == 0){
            result.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return result || c;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use `array.includes`. It's easier to use and you get faster results...

**Example:**

```js
let search = 'test'
let list = ['te', 'test', 'sample', 'john']
list.includes(search.toLowerCase()) // returns the `te` and `test`
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the op's question in two ways: (1) they want it to return an array, not a boolean; (2) they want to do a partial "starts with" match and `includes` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hasan Parasteh was sort of on to something with their answer, however as thdoan pointed out the .includes method when used on an array only finds exact matches. I then remembered using .includes on string and they do partial matches on strings, so what you could do is array.toString().includes() which is working perfectly for me now for my particular situation.

This probably won't work in various other situations but if you simply just want to check if an array contains a specific phrase, this could be one way to do it without having to add iteration into the mix.

What is another positive is when converting array to a string it adds commas, there for you don't end up with one giant word which might combine other words to make the phrase you are looking for like I originally worried about, so it legit finds partial matches!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I figured I'd respond to the person who commented to inform them that I am sorry my answer was above their level of comprehension. Whether or not something is unclear is highly subjective due to the fact that people vary in intelligence and thus vary in their abilities to comprehend things, but it was a bot which said it which they are even less intelligent than humans therefor it's comment is completely invalid and I will not edit the post to dumb it down to it's level as that would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think Fralcon's answer is good, but there is an error in the condition.
Change this for proper functionality:

```
if (this[i].indexOf(candid) == 0) {
        return i;
}
```

to this:

```
if (this[i].indexOf(candid) != -1) {
        return i;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35661185)